# Slow connection speed while uploading data more than 1MB to IIS

Tags: c#, iis-7, http-post, u2, universe

I am using IIS as my web server. I am going to use this web server to receive data from a a http client on a Universe database. Whenever i send a Post request that has more than 1 MB then the data transfer speed is merely around 12 KB per second. But if the data is less than a MB then it transfers at around 800 KB per second.

So i did a research by using apache as a web server and transfer speed was almost equal to available bandwidth. So i though IIS is the culprit but i tried to send a post request using curl from php to IIS and it can transfer at full bandwidth. Now it got weird and i dont know what to do.

please help

Comment: Can you break your data into pieces and upload each independently?  It's a pain to do, but it's one way to get around the throttling you're experiencing.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i was thinking about it but i am not comfortable because the data i am sending is very sensitive and i don't want to mess it. I thought i can change to Java

Comment: If you have server and/or networking support people, talk to them.  The throttling might be a simple configuration change.

Comment: It seems like handshaking issue between IIS server and the httpclient in Universe Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer size in the httpClient was configured improperly . The buffer size on the httpclient cannot be more than a Megabyte. I am not sure whether the issue with the http client or the IIS server because the httpClient can send data with greater buffer size >1MB to the Apache server.

Solution is I set the buffersize less than a MB and it works good now.